# Update angularjs view on demand

Tags: angularjs, view, updatemodel

I have an angular controller as such:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
   var dao = new MyDao();
   var something = dao.getSomething();
   $scope.something = something;
   // update view            

   var somethingElse = dao.getSomethingElse();
   $scope.somethingElse = somethingElse;
   // update view again
});
```

This controller is tied to a view through a routing config. Method getSomething() and getSomethingElse() can take several seconds to execute, so I'd like to update the view as soon as each method returns it data. I read that I should be able to do this by adding `$scope.$apply();` where the comments are, but angular is throwing an error: `Error: [$rootScope:inprog]`. Can someone explain why or provide a better alternative? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to trigger a digest cycle (via `$apply()`) while one is already happening.

You can use `$timeout()` it will trigger a digest if needed or continue normally if one is already in progress.

```
$timeout(function() {
  // anything you want can go here and will safely be run on the next digest.
})
```

You can also check if `$scope.$$phase` is false (meaning angular is not in the middle of a digest) before using `$apply()`, but that is unadvised.

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
  //$digest or $apply
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide your view until something comes back like this:

```
<div ng-show="something.length">
  {{something}}
</div>
```

In addition, you can add a loading message until your something comes back:

```
<div ng-show="loading">Loading something...</div>
```